# AnnotationHub Resource | Failed to load Resource | Download Issue in R

Tags: r, annotations, data-science, genome

When I run Command ah[[1]] I faced the following Problem:

retrieving 1 resource
Error: failed to load resource
  name: AH5087
  title: ORegAnno
  reason: 1 resources failed to download
In addition: Warning messages:
1: download failed
  web resource path: ‘https://annotationhub.bioconductor.org/fetch/5087’
  local file path: ‘/home/hafizahmad/.cache/AnnotationHub/bf61af04785_5087’
  reason: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number 
2: bfcadd() failed; resource removed
  rid: BFC8
  fpath: ‘https://annotationhub.bioconductor.org/fetch/5087’
  reason: download failed 
3: download failed
  hub path: ‘https://annotationhub.bioconductor.org/fetch/5087’
  cache resource: ‘AH5087 : 5087’
  reason: bfcadd() failed; see warnings() 
.

I described the solution of problem is described below in answer:
downloading 1 resources

Comment: There's no code or context and no clear question here. Your answer isn't clear either, since we don't know what the code is that you've fixed. Please revisit [ask] and make this a [mcve] for it to help other users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just write **ah[[2,force=TRUE]]** instead of ah[[2]]

Answer (score 1):

Adding more context here because this helped me. I tried to load a Mus musculus database with AnnotationHub() and was given a similar error:

```
Error: failed to load resource
  name: AH109367
  title: Ensembl 108 EnsDb for Mus musculus
  reason: database disk image is malformed
```

I found some other links with similar issues [here](https://support.bioconductor.org/p/9139964/) and [here](https://support.bioconductor.org/p/70630/) but neither of those solutions worked for me.

The answer above fixed my issue and I was able to load the data.

Original Code:

```
library(AnnotationHub); library(tidyverse)
# Connect to AnnotationHub
ah <- AnnotationHub()

# Access the Ensembl database for organism
ahDb <- query(ah, 
              pattern = c("Mus musculus", "EnsDb"), 
              ignore.case = TRUE)

# Acquire the latest annotation files
id <- ahDb %>%
        mcols() %>%
        rownames() %>%
        tail(n = 1)

# Download the appropriate Ensembldb database
edb <- ah[[id]]
```

New Code:

```
# Connect to AnnotationHub
ah <- AnnotationHub()

# Access the Ensembl database for organism
ahDb <- query(ah, 
              pattern = c("Mus musculus", "EnsDb"), 
              ignore.case = TRUE)

# Acquire the latest annotation files
id <- ahDb %>%
        mcols() %>%
        rownames() %>%
        tail(n = 1)

# Download the appropriate Ensembldb database
edb <- ah[[id, force=T]]
```

Comment: It still not works for me ;) After I change the id to the last second, it works!